# C# : Removing an item from a List<T> without knowing its index?

Tags: c#, list

I'm using FileSystemWatcher class to monitor a folder and update the list as events arise.  I'm using the following class to hold information for each file:

```
public class FileItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

The following list holds the collection of that information:

```
public static List<FileItem> folder = new List<FileItem>();
```

I added some FileItem objects into the list.  However, to remove a specific item that has a matching name, I couldn't just use foreach() loop because enumerations change and as soon as the file is removed, I get an exception.  So, I added a break (since there will only be one file with the same name) to break out of the foreach() loop after an item was removed... but I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way to do it.  Is there a simpler and more appropriate way?  Here's my code for the removal:

```
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted)
    {
        foreach (var item in folder)
        {
            if (item.Name == e.Name)
            {
                folder.Remove(item);
                folder.TrimExcess();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a `Dictionary<>` instead, for efficient removal. Your code will execute really slow if you've got a lot of stuff in your `List<>`.

Comment: @CoryNelson Hmm, so like this? Dictionary<string, string> where the first string is file name and the second one is path?

Comment: @Noobacode: That might be tricky; you may want to have `List<string>` as your value (i.e. `Dictionary<string, List<FileItem>>`) unless you don't expect to have the same file _name_ in multiple different unique paths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can remove any item by populating it through linq and then removing it from the list

```
List<FileItem> folder = new List<FileItem>();
folder.Remove(folder.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Name == "myname"));
folder.Remove(folder.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Path == "mypath"));
```

Comment: Here you are finding a value through LINQ, not removing one. On one hand I prefer this over Nikhil's answer because it enforces the contract of "there will only be one file with the same name", but on the other this will force a full scan of the list every time, so it will be slower.

Comment: Brilliant!  You just reduced that block of code down to one line.  I assume I would still need to trim the excess of the list?

Comment: Any reason to use `SingleOrDefault` here instead of `FirstOrDefault`? With `SingleOrDefault` it will iterate the entire list even once it finds a match looking for duplicates. Unless you want it to throw an exception because you have more than one matching entry?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair SingleOrDefault is probably a good way to protect against duplicates since it'll throw an exception.  But I'm assuming FirstOrDefault would be quicker since it MIGHT not have not go through the entire list.

Comment: @Noobacode: That's exactly what I suggested. So to me it depends on what you want to do Noobacode: if you have duplicates in your list, do you want to A) remove them as well (use [`List.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) instead), B) throw an exception (use `SingleOrDefault`), or C) do nothing, essentially just remove the first entry (use `FirstOrDefault`)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair For some odd reason it's not letting me substitute Remove with RemoveAll in this code.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I also wonder why I can't just use folder.RemoveAll(x => x.Name == e.Name)?

Comment: @Noobacode: The code would be slightly different as you would supply your lambda expression directly: `folder.RemoveAll(x => x.Name == "myname");` EDIT: Regarding your latest comment, you _should_ be able to. What compiler error are you getting?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair None, I was just wondering why I would use LINQ syntax over using lamba expression directly?

Comment: @Noobacode: Sorry for the delay, the primary reason why would be the intended behaviour/result. In my previous comment I pointed out that using `RemoveAll()` would remove _all_ matches, where as the `Remove(LINQ)` version would only remove the _first_ match found. So use the version which best matches your _intended behaviour_.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted)
    {
        FileItem item = folder.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == e.Name);

        if (item != null)
            folder.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` also takes a predicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a for loop

```
for(int x = folder.Count() - 1; x>=0; x--)
{
  if (folder[x].Name == e.Name)
    {
      folder.Remove(folder[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: As soon as you remove one, your indexes will get fudged and you'll inadvertently end up skipping elements

Comment: That is a lie; I use this method for most of my codes where I want to remove something from a list in a loop.
Please do your research before you down vote.

Comment: No "research" to be done, but I *was* missing the fact that you were iterating from the tail and not the head. Yes, this should work because a `List<T>` will maintain indexes after removal. The only word of caution I will say is if the OP changes from `List<T>` to something else which does not guarantee indexes remain constant, this could break in the future.

Comment: @ismellike - I agree with lc. This is a bad idea to remove items like this. It is implementation dependent.

Comment: This will fail if `folder[x]` exists twice in a list. If you use `RemoveAt`, it will be perfectly safe _and_ faster.

Comment: @Enigmativity what about it will be implementation-defined?

Comment: @CoryNelson - You can't rely on the implementation of `List<T>` behaving in this way in the future. Right now it is an array under the hood, but it could change and this code could then fail.

Comment: @Enigmativity Random-access by index is defined by `List<>`, not its implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you can restructure your data, here is a `Dictionary<>` based approach:

```
// let the key be Name, and value be Path.
public static Dictionary<string, string> folder = new Dictionary<string, string>();

private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted)
    {
        folder.Remove(e.Name);
    }
}
```

This will be much more performant as the size of `folder` increases, because `Dictionary<>` operations are amortized O(1) while `List<>.Remove` is O(n).

This also explicitly enforces your contract of "there will only be one file with the same name", as that is a basic property of `Dictionary<>`.

You might want to pass in `StringComparer.InvariantIgnoreCase` to the dictionary's constructor, as file names are case-insensitive on Windows. This is platform-dependent -- Linux is case-sensitive -- so if you're making a shared library that needs to be robust and cross-platform, you'll want to figure out a way to [select the correct comparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430256/how-do-i-determine-whether-the-filesystem-is-case-sensitive-in-net). This issue affects *all* answers, not just mine.

Comment: Thank you very much for the example.  I will test both cases and see if there is a significant enough of a performance difference in my case.