# Comparing two paths in C#. When do I use case-sensitivity?

Tags: c#, .net, file, filesystems, filepath

I am currently writing a compiler and I have a small class that loops through the input files and compares them to see if there's no repeated files. Of course, we can't compare the strings directly because the same file can be written like, let's say, `main.c` and `./main.c`. Therefore, I am using `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath()` to compare the file paths. The problem is that on Windows, the filesystems aren't case sensitive so, `"C:/main.c" == "C:/Main.c"`, for example but, on *NIX systems like Linux, Mac or Android, these two could be different files. Also, *NIX also supports filesystems like FAT and FAT32, that work like Windows' ones. How do I know when I should compare the two paths with or without case-sensitivity, so that I can firmly whether the 2 file paths are equal or different?

Comment: It's even worse, since C:\Temp might be a folder, or it might be a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430256/how-do-i-determine-whether-the-filesystem-is-case-sensitive-in-net

Comment: @DaveM it didn't appear in the search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pinvoke the Shell API function SHParseDisplayName, then call the CompareIDs method on the IShellFolder interface returned by SHGetDesktopFolder.

If you can drop XP support you can use Microsoft's Windows-API-Code-Pack. Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.ShellObject.Equals would do the comparison.

Comment: Thanks but I managed to create a solution using `DriveInfo.GetDrives()` and getting the file format.

Comment: The problem is that I can't use WinAPI on Mono. I am now trying to see if the file exists in both upper and lower case. If that's true, the file system is not case-sensitive. Because I already handled non-existing files and I don't create new files, this works in read-only filesystems or when we don't have permission to create files. The only flaw is that if the file has no letters to test lower and upper case. That was fixed by making my compiler refuse files without the programming language file extension, in this case, ".icpl"